# R - ggplot pie chart with facet_wrap

Tags: r, ggplot2

Do I understand it correctly that it is not possible to fully use the facet_wrap with pie chart (ggplot + coord_polar) ?

```
library(ggplot2)
library(data.table)

c1 <- c(1,2,3,1,2,3)
c2 <- c("first","second","third","first","second","third")
c2 <- factor(c2, levels = c("first","second","third"))
c3 <- c(0.2,0.3,0.5,0.4,0.5,0.1)
c4 <- c("A","A","A","B","B","B")
c4 <- factor(c4, levels = c("A","B"))
cs <- data.frame(c1,c2,c3,c4)
ct <- data.table(cs)
ct[,midpoint:=cumsum(c3) - c3/2,by=c4]

colx <- c("blue","yellow","green")
ct[,colx:=colx,by=c4]

   c1     c2  c3 c4 midpoint   colx
1:  1  first 0.2  A     0.10   blue
2:  2 second 0.3  A     0.35 yellow
3:  3  third 0.5  A     0.75  green
4:  1  first 0.4  B     0.20   blue
5:  2 second 0.5  B     0.65 yellow
6:  3  third 0.1  B     0.95  green


vysg <- ggplot(ct, aes(x=1,y=c3,fill=c2)) + 
          geom_bar(stat="identity",width=2) + 
          coord_polar(theta='y')+
          theme(axis.ticks=element_blank(), axis.title=element_blank(), 
            axis.text.y = element_blank(), panel.grid  = element_blank(),
            axis.text.x = element_text(color=ct[,colx],size=15,hjust=0))+ 
        scale_y_continuous(breaks = ct[,midpoint], labels = ct[,c2])  + 
        scale_fill_manual(values=ct[,colx]) +
        scale_x_continuous(limits=c(-1,2.5))
vysg<-vysg+facet_wrap(~ c4)
vysg
```

[image]

The shares seem correct but the labels and their positions are not. 
Is there any way how to use facetting or is it necessary to use grids?

And I know that pie chart is not the best one.

Comment: It would be easy to use `geom_text`, such as `+  geom_text(aes(x = 2.5, y = midpoint, label = c2, colour = c2))`

Comment: Thanks. I have posted the solution with your improvement as an answer. It works perfectly. If you want, post it yourself and I will delete my version. Just wanted to show the result.

Comment: You don't have to do it.  You can change the distance between pie and labels by using more big value as below xxx, `scale_x_continuous(limits=c(-1, xxx))` and `geom_text(aes(x = xxx, y = ...))`. And you can use bold font by `geom_text(aes(...), fontface = "bold")`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to cuttlefish44 useful comment, the code would look like this

```
library(ggplot2)
library(data.table)

c1 <- c(1,2,3,1,2,3)
c2 <- c("first","second","third","first","second","third")
c2 <- factor(c2, levels = c("first","second","third"))
c3 <- c(0.2,0.3,0.5,0.4,0.5,0.1)
c4 <- c("A","A","A","B","B","B")
c4 <- factor(c4, levels = c("A","B"))
cs <- data.frame(c1,c2,c3,c4)
ct <- data.table(cs)
ct[,midpoint:=cumsum(c3) - c3/2,by=c4]

colx <- c("blue","yellow","green")
ct[,colx:=colx,by=c4]
ct

   c1     c2  c3 c4 midpoint   colx
1:  1  first 0.2  A     0.10   blue
2:  2 second 0.3  A     0.35 yellow
3:  3  third 0.5  A     0.75  green
4:  1  first 0.4  B     0.20   blue
5:  2 second 0.5  B     0.65 yellow
6:  3  third 0.1  B     0.95  green


vysg <- ggplot(ct, aes(x=1,y=c3,fill=c2)) + 
          geom_bar(stat="identity",width=2) + 
          coord_polar(theta='y')+
        theme(axis.ticks=element_blank(), axis.title=element_blank(),axis.text.y = element_blank(),axis.text.x = element_blank(), panel.grid  = element_blank())+
        geom_text(aes(x = 2.5, y = midpoint, label = c2, colour = I(colx)))+
        scale_x_continuous(limits=c(-1,2.5))+
        scale_fill_manual(values=colx)
vysg<-vysg+facet_wrap(~ c4)
vysg
```

[image]